# Lightbox - Pictures are not responsive

Tags: lightbox

I have a problem when I try to reduce the browser window, the photo does not want to fit.
Does anyone have any idea? Thanks for your help.

Link to page:
http://pomyslownia.twsoft.pl/realizacje_post_type/xvd/

before reduce the browser window:
[image: before reduce the browser window]

after reduce the browser window:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following rules to your css:

```
/* *********************** responsive lightbox */

.lb-outerContainer {
    width:100% !important;
    max-width:1000px !important;
    height:auto !important;
    }
.lb-outerContainer IMG {
    width:100% !important;
    max-width:1000px !important;
    height:auto !important;
    }
.lb-dataContainer {
    width:100% !important;
    max-width:1000px !important;
    }
```

This should make Lightbox images responsive.